# Codename One - BarCode Scanner

Tags: java, codenameone

I am using the latest API (CodeScanner and ScanResult) for barcode scanning and wanted to ask if the following is possible:

I want to open the scan window and after I scan a product, a dialog window pops up, letting me select the quantity. While doing this, the scan widow must stay opened, so after I input the amount of the first product, I can scan the next product and so on, until I decide to stop scanning.

The way I am doing it now is too slow, cause the scan window closes after the first scan and I have to open it again after I input the quantity. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Codenameone apps open the native scanner when you try to scan and there's a callback to the app after scanning.

What I will suggest you do is place 2 commands on your Dialog, one will end the scan process and the other will initiate a new scan if user desires.

```
Dialog dlg = new Dialog();
dlg.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
TextField txtQuantity = new TextField();
dlg.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, BoxLayout.encloseY(txtQuantity));

dlg.placeButtonCommands(new Command[]{new Command("Continue") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        this.setDisposesDialog(true);
        dlg.dispose();
    }
}, new Command("Scan new") {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        this.setDisposesDialog(true);
        //Initiate a new scan here
    }
}});
```

Then in your scan callback, show this dialog. You can wrap this in a method and call this method recursively inside the **Scan new** actionPerformed.

Comment: FYI the barcode scan API is now deprecated and will be removed soon so another option is also to edit the actual native library that replaces it here: https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan/